# Why perturbation expansion can only expand around stationary point?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, perturbation-theory

I only recently became aware of this question. Why perturbation expansion is only valid in expand near the stationary point? I've been told it will go for divergent if expand around unstable point, I wonder how to see such a divergence? Any examples?

Answer (score 1):

That’s easy enough.  Take a pendulum.

Near the bottom (usually $\theta=0$), you can expand the potential to get harmonic motion.  Since the solution is in $\cos(\theta)$ and $\sin(\theta)$, both of which are bounded function, you can never go “far” from your initial conditions.

One the other hand, near $\theta=\pi$ the pendulum is near upright.  If you expand near this point, you find the solutions are exponentials, which are unbounded.  (If you actually carry the expansion the potential is an inverted parabola near this point, so a marble would roll away from the top of the inverted bowl.) Thus, you always go exponentially “far” from your initial conditions.

Near $\theta=\pi$:
$$
\cos(\pi+\delta\theta)\approx -1+\frac{1}{2}\delta\theta
$$
so the potential
$$
mg L(1-\cos\theta)\approx -\textstyle\frac{1}{2}mgL  \delta\theta^2 
$$ up to some constant.  Thus,
the equation of motion near this point is
$$
\ddot{\theta}=\frac{g}{L}\delta\theta  \tag{1}
$$
with solution $\theta(t)=A e^{\omega t} + B e^{-\omega t}$, where $\omega=\sqrt{g/L}$.  You can see that the sign on the RHS of Eq.(1) is crucial.  Near the stable fixed point, the RHS is $- g \delta /L$ so the solutions are in $\sin(\omega t)$ and $\cos(\omega t)$, but near the unstable fixed point the positive sign forces the solutions to be exponentials.

You *can* expand about unstable points but the solutions do not stay close to such points over long timescales so this is not really useful unless you are interested in the very short term behaviour of the system.

Comment: In fact, it is often not known whether a particular solution of the equations of motion is stable or unstable, and the way to assess its stability is to do a perturbation analysis about the solution and see what happens.

Comment: Sorry about ask, could you please give some more details? You means when I expand the pendulum potential: $mgL(1 – COS\theta)$ around $\theta=\pi$ then I can get exponential?

Comment: I added a bit of details.